# How do I prove that for every positive integer $ n$, there exist $2n$ consecutive positive integers, each of which is composite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I honestly need help with this question. I'm not asking for the answer but can someone at least point in the right direction to prove this? I know a prime number is one whose factors are itself and 1 otherwise they are composite numbers. So I basically need to prove that there is a sequence of 2n consecutive positive integers containing no primes but I don't know where to start?  Do I define an integer x and multiply by 2? If so then I know that will always be composite. I'm afraid I'm going in the wrong direction. If anyone can just point me right I'd appreciate it.

EDIT TO SHOW WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR:
Proof: Given $n>0$
For every number in the set $1,2,3,4,5\cdots n+1$, $x=(2n!)$

(Now I know that any number $2n!$ is a composite number but I don't know how to prove that formally)

Comment: Look at $(2n)!$. Is it composite? What about the numbers that come afterwards?

Comment: That's the only part I have been able to figure out so far. I know 2n! will give you a composite number every time but I don't know how to put that into a formal proof. I'm still relatively new to proof writing.

Comment: Take $(2n)!+2$ which number do you think will divide this number? It is useful to remember that $(2n)!=2\cdot 3\cdot \dots \cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n)$.

Comment: Do I need to add a variable x?  and show x!+2, x!+3, …, x!+x is a sequence of x-1 composite numbers.

and set x >= 2n+1?

Comment: For a positive natural number $m\geq 2$ we have $m!=2\cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (m-1)\cdot m$. I.e. it is the product of all positive natural numbers less or equal to $m$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $(2n)! +2$ is divisible by $2$? Then try to generalize this reasoning to $(2n)!+3$.

Comment: I assume 2n! would give me an even number and if I add 2 then it would still be even and therefore divisible by 2

Comment: $2n!$ means $2(n!)$, not $(2n)!$ The distinction is important!

Comment: Also, how is it possible that you don't know how to show that $(2n)!$ is composite (when $n\ge 2$)? You just have to exhibit a factor greater than $1$ and less than $(2n)!$

Comment: Forget writing the proof for a minute. Do you see why $6!+2, 6!+3, ... , 6!+6$ are all composite? How many are in that list? What if you start with $16!+2$ and do the same thing — how many consecutive composites are you sure to find? What would would you start with if you wanted $27$ consecutive composites? And if you wanted $m$ consecutive, start with what? And for $2n$, start with what?

Comment: No I hate to say I don't know why that makes the answers all composite. ??

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple ways.

One requires a rather strong theorem: If pi(n) is the number of primes ≤ n, then the limit of n / (pi(n) log n) is 1. So the average gap between two primes becomes larger and larger, therefore the maximum gap between primes becomes larger and larger, therefore there will eventually be two primes separated by 2n or more composite numbers.

One doesn't require much mathematics at all: The number (2n+1)! is the product of all integers from 1 to 2n+1, and therefore divisible by all integers from 1 to 2n+1. (2n+1)! + 2 is divisible by 2, (2n+1)! + 3 is divisible by 3 etc. until (2n+1)! + (2n+1) is divisible by 2n+1. These numbers are therefore all composite, and there are 2n of them.